# Unity: Camera.main is failing after I switch scenes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having a weird issue with some of my code, and I could really use some help.

I have a script attached to a gameobject that is unique to a particular scene, so anything within Start() will only run when that scene is loaded. In this script, I am accessing Camera.main, since I use settings attached to the camera gameobject (it may sound inefficient, but it is necessary for the style of game we are creating). Anyway, if I start from that scene directly in Unity, it works just fine, but if I start from my intro scene and then load into the aforementioned scene, I get this error:

```
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Camera' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
```

The weird thing is, I can Debug.Log(Camera.main) and it gives me the name of the camera. So Camera.main is not null, and it is not destroyed like it says in the error message. Here is my full script:

```
private void Start()
    {
        Debug.LogError(Camera.main);
        gameManager = FindObjectOfType<GameManagerScript>();
        if (Camera.main == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Camera.main is null");
        }
        else
        {
            gameManager.LoadMusic(Camera.main);
            gameManager.LoadAmbient(Camera.main);
            gameManager.FadeStereoPan(Camera.main.gameObject.GetComponent<SwipeActivator>().stereoPanInNode);
        }
    }
```

The three functions above are custom functions I wrote, but I don't know why they would be causing the issue, since they work if I start up the scene directly.

I wasn't having this issue for months, and then all of a sudden, I am getting this error, even though I didn't change any of the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Camera.main` will get the camera that has the tag `Main Camera`

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have clarified. This game we are creating has many cameras, as it is a Myst-style first person point-and-click. I currently have all of the cameras set as Main Camera, and I simply enable/disable them as necessary to move from one point to another.

Comment: Do you get the error every time? Are you 100% sure you haven't changed the code?  Make sure that there aren't any dependencies on which order the Start() methods are running, for example "Script X's Start() must run before Y's Start() for Z to work"

Comment: Oh wait, did you say that you disable it? `Camera.main` will return `null` if there are no active cameras tagged with `Main Camera`. But your error says Destroyed. Do you ever Destroy cameras?

Comment: That is what I was confused about originally, as I don't ever destroy cameras, but as I said in my answer, the reason it was failing was because I have a DontDestroyOnLoad() object that was pointing to a camera in the previous scene, and when I switched scenes, it was failing because I hadn't yet reassigned that variable to a camera in the new scene.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your MainCamera is being destroyed between scenes. Set it up as "DontDestroyOnLoad()"

See this Unity question:
https://answers.unity.com/questions/430141/need-the-same-main-camera-for-multiple-scenes.html

Comment: Please see my comment posted to the question. I can't set it up as DontDestroyOnLoad since I need to be using a different camera at that time. I actually just want to grab the currently activated camera, but even Camera.current doesn't help me. My main issue is that I can't figure out is why Debug.Log(Camera.main) works, providing me the name of the active camera, but my custom function that accepts a camera is providing the missing error. My function works in every other scenario, so it would seem unlikely that it would be an issue with the function, but I will check again just to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I fixed it. I dove into my custom functions and found that I was accessing a camera variable that is set at the beginning of the game, and then on each camera transition, but it was failing since I was loading a scene and no transitions that scene had yet to be completed. I just had to reassign that variable in the script above so it was not pointing to the destroyed object in the previous scene. Thank you JiveTurkey for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Reading is not my strong suit. :)